# How to rebuild the source tables of an active form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have an Access Form whose source data is 2 tables, let's call them `TblA` and `TblB`. This form has a control that should:

1. Capture some new data from the user into a 3rd table.
2. Run maketable queries recreating TblA and TblB with the new data.
3. Requery & refresh the form.

However, I'm running into a problem.  The maketable queries are failing.  I assume this is because I have the main form open.  Here's a code snippet:

```
Dim AccDB As New Access.Application
AccDB.OpenCurrentDatabase DbLoc
AccDB.DoCmd.OpenQuery "TblA-Rebuild"
AccDB.DoCmd.OpenQuery "TblB-Rebuild"
Forms("Frm").Requery
```

My question is: How do rewrite this process to successfully rebuild these tables?

Comment: What happens if you set the row source to nothing, make your table then try rebinding the form? Failing that can you go unbound with the form?

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I added code to save the form's recordsource, set it to null, run the queries, and reset it back to the original.  But I still have the same problem.

Comment: After you change the table structures of TblA and TblB, do you also have to modify the form's controls to work with the revised table structures?

Comment: @Hansup, the tables have no special settings in them and the MakeTable queries are very standard.  Whatever the MakeTable queries create, the form uses.

Comment: I have never deployed a MakeTable in a production application. It is something that is useful for data massage and archiving data and such, but does not belong in a production app. Instead, create a table in a temp database with the appropriate structure, and empty it and append data to it as needed. This will remove the problem you've encountered entirely because you will only be altering the data, not the table itself.

Comment: Thanks David. That's the option I eventually chose and it's working out just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would further suggest rather than re-creating the tables that you use a delete query to clear the contents and then an append query to refill the table. No conflicts with the table being in use and you don't lose table settings like indexes or field-specific properties.

Comment: At first, I hesitated on this idea because it seemed too complicated.  But now, I realize it's much simpler than the other options.

Answer (score 0):

I would embed your existing form into a subform that isn't bound to a table.  Then you can close your subform while you're remaking the tables and open it again.